# Assembly Language (Find the following query as mentioned below)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Need help on below code and queries.

My understanding of the code below suggests it will get stuck in an infinite loop.

1. What is the return value from DemoFunction2?
2. What is the purpose of DemoFunction2?

   ```
   //

   0:000> uf    010024d0

   asmdemo2!DemoFunction2:

   010024d0 55                push    ebp

   010024d1 8bec              mov     ebp,esp                

   010024d3 8b5508            mov     edx,dword ptr [ebp+8] 

   010024d6 33c0              xor     eax,eax               

   010024d8 b920000000        mov     ecx,20h              

   010024dd d1ea              shr     edx,1               

   010024df 7301              jnc     asmdemo2!DemoFunction2+0x12 (010024e2)

   010024e1 40                inc     eax                   

   010024e2 e2f9              loop    asmdemo2!DemoFunction2+0xd (010024dd)

   010024e4 5d                pop     ebp

   010024e5 c3                ret


   0:000> r
   eax=80002418    ebx=7ffd7000    ecx=00682295   edx=00000000   esi=80002418 
   edi=00000002
   eip=010024d0   esp=0006fe98    ebp=0006fea8    iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na 
   pe nc
   cs=001b    ss=0023   ds=0023   es=0023   fs=003b   gs=0000             
   efl=00000246

   asmdemo2!DemoFunction2:

   010024d0 55              push    ebp

   0:000> dps   esp

   0006fe98  0100251c asmdemo2!main+0x20

   0006fe9c  80002418

   0006fea0  00000002 

   0006fea4  00000000

   0006fea8  0006ff88

   0006feac  01002969 asmdemo2!_mainCRTStartup+0x12c

   0006feb0  00000002

   0006feb4  00682270

   0006feb8  006822b8

   0006febc  f395c17d

   0006fec0  00000000

   0006fec4  00000000

   0006fec8  7ffd7000

   0006fecc  00000000

   0006fed0  00000000

   0006fed4  00000000

   0006fed8  00000094

   0006fedc  00000006

   0006fee0  00000000

   0006fee4  00001771

   0006fee8  00000002

   0006feec  76726553

   0006fef0  20656369

   0006fef4  6b636150

   0006fef8  00003120

   0006fefc  00000000

   0006ff00  00000000

   0006ff04  00000000

   0006ff08  00000000

   0006ff0c  00000000

   0006ff10  00000000

   0006ff14  00000000
   ```

Comment: Seems to count the number of bits set in the 32-bit value (that is what the 0x20=32 is for the loop) that is passed as the first parameter.

Comment: yes, ecx =20h (32d) ,however what would be a return value in this program.

Comment: As I said it counts the number of bits set in the first argument passed. _EAX_ will be the number of bits set.

Comment: It seems like an infinite loop to me too. The first jnc skips the inc eax, but then the unconditional loop goes back to the shr again.

Comment: ECX is set to 32. Each time the loop instruction is executed it reduces ECX by 1. This continues until it reaches 0. EDX start with the value of the first parameter passed. On each iteration the value (in EDX) is shifted right by 1 bit. The value of the right most bit will be shifted out and into the carry flag. When the carry flag is set EAX is increased by 1 otherwise EAX is unchanged. This is done 32 times which in effect counts all the bits that were set to 1.

Comment: @Harun: The [_LOOP_ instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html) is not unconditional.. It reduces ECX by 1 then compares if ECX is 0. If it is not zero the loop branches back to the offset specified otherwise ECX is 0 and it falls through to the next instruction after the loop instruction

Comment: 010024dd d1ea              shr     edx,1    // This doesn't seem to be setting a carry flag and because of this, it seems to be jumping on this function " jnc     asmdemo2!DemoFunction2+0x12 (010024e2)"  infinitely .

Comment: The carry flag will be set to 1 if the right most bit in EDX is 1 otherwise it will be zero.

Comment: Right, however here value is 32 and right most bit is 0

Comment: _EDX_ doesn't contain the value 32, _EAX_ does.

Comment: It seems EAX, will only increment to 32 if programs come out of JNC instruction. what are your thoughts ?

Comment: The LOOP instruction decreases _ECX_ by one each time it is executed. if the value in _ECX_ becomes 0 the loop exits. That is how the loop ends - when ECX reaches 0. EAX is used as a counter to keep track of the number of bits shifted out that were set to 1.

Comment: A copy of the Instruction Set Reference is here: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/  . It tells you what each instruction does.

Comment: Ah of course! Beg pardon, I haven't used the loop instruction for ages.

Comment: If I'm reading that stack output correctly in the question the value at _EBP+8_ (same as _ESP+4_ after EBP is pushed) is 0x80002418. 0x8002418 = binary 10000000000000000010010000011000 . There are 5 bits set to 1. When this function exits EAX will have the value 5.

Comment: Perfect.  EDX indeed has a value 10000000000000000010010000011000, which will  make EAX to inc 5 times. However that doesn't end the loop count and JNC will make it Jump on that function,once the carry bit stop getting set.

Comment: You still don't understand LOOP decrements _ECX_ each time the loop instruction is encountered and then compares ECX with zero. If it is zero the loop exits. that is the way that loop exits. I don't think you have looked at the instruction set. `loop branch_target` is the same as replacing it with `dec ecx` followed by `jnz branch_target` where branch_target is where to go back to when ECX is not zero.

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment the documentation for how the _LOOP_ instruction works can be found here; http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right and I went through it, however we are only encountering loop instruction 5 times, as we are only setting carry flag for 5 times, JNC means it will make the code flow jump back to the function if carry flag is not set.

Comment: The loop is always done 32 times (ECX is initially set to 0x20=32 decimal). the `SHR` instruction is done once each loop. If the bit shifted off the right is set then the Carry Flag (CF) will be set and EAX is incremented by one and loop continues. If CF was clear (bit shifted out was not set) _EAX_ is not incremented and the loop continues.

Comment: Alright , it means JNC is only skipping the increment of EAX if carry flag is not set, however this instruction will end once ECX reaches 0 and will stay inside that loop ?

Comment: The loop instruction will finish when _ECX_ is zero at which point it falls through to the `pop ebp` otherwise it goes back to the top of the loop and continues.

Comment: You are genius and Geek (Compliment) :), have a Great day ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not an infinite loop.

At the beginning `ecx` is set to 32.
Every time the [`loop` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html) executes ecx is decremented by 1.
When ecx reaches 0, the loop instruction will fall through (not jump) and the instructions thereafter will be executed (`pop`+`ret`).

Obviously the code is inefficient.

A simple

```
popcnt eax,[esp+4]
ret
```

Would do the same function much faster, but it works.

It counts the number of set bits in the first argument, using the cdecl calling convention.